# How to know when async recursion activities have finished?

Tags: javascript, events, asynchronous, recursion, yui

I have a script that builds a list based on a directory structure. It reads from WebDAV resources to discover locks, per-file, and appends nodes and classes to display this structure as a series of nested lists with a class on a list item if it is locked.

That all works wonderfully, what I want to do now is assign functionality to the created list nodes.

I could add this functionality as the list item is created within the scope of the async callback, but I was wondering if there were any common approaches out there which might wait for a series of potentially recursive async activities (X-level directories with Y resources in them) to finish, and at that point safely perform actions on the whole group of created nodes.

The reason I ask, instead of going ahead and adding functionality during each async callback for a discovered resource, is because I am using YUI3 and they have all sorts of conveniences like:

```
// Add functionality to items meeting the CSS selector criteria
Y.all('#select_projects_list li.file:not(#select_projects_list li.locked)').on('click', function(e){
    // do stuff with 'this'
});
```

Where it would seem that if I did the above it might be more efficient than repeating a similar function within each async callback for what might end up being hundreds of resources.

Pseudo-code solutions, ideas and approaches appreciated.

cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event delegation.  In general, if you find yourself using `Y.all(...).on(...)`, you should probably be using event delegation.

Try this:

```
Y.one('#select_projects_list').delegate('click', handleClick, 'li.file:not(.locked)');
```

`handleClick` will be called for any click that happens on any li inside #select_projects_list that has class "file" and doesn't have class "locked".  If you later add, remove, or change any of these li nodes, you won't need to do any more or change any event subscriptions.  The one delegate listener will do.  Inside the handleClick callback, `this` will be the li node.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/event/#delegate

Comment: beaut. worked a charm, definitely awesome that I can delegate the functionality before the nodes exist, thanks Luke!